# Filling Excel cell programatically with a IF formula doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-interop, comexception

I'm trying to fill an Excel 2010 cell programatically via COM Interop, with a string that represents an IF-formula.

The following line of code works just fine, it resolves to value 4 in Excel:

```
 .Range("C10").Value = "=2+2"
```

but when I pass an IF-Formula (as String)...

```
 .Range("C11").Value = "=IF(1+1=2;2;0)"
```

...I run into a `COMException`, saying: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`.

If I enter the same IF-formula directly in Excel, it is parsed correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the semicolons with commas and use `.Formula` instead `.Value`

```
.Range("C11").Formula= "=IF(1+1=2,2,0)"
```

Comment: without more information, it's likely that the semicolons are there due to locality preferences, since the OP says the formula works when typed into the cell. +1 for the `.Formula` update